# MultiBinding And MultiTrigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

...So I have 2 elements, i want that the IsChecked property of the checbox will binded to my
'IsAlwaysOn' property which is in my My Class object(Two Way), and to an element combox selected value properties, where if the value is 'enter', then IsChecked is false,
any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a DataTrigger, however I wouldn't recommend it because the value of the CheckBox would not always get saved to `MyClass.IsAlwaysOn`

```
<Style x:Key="MyCheckBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsAlwaysOn}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyComboBox, Path=SelectedValue}" Value="Enter">
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
</Style>
```

Instead, I would recommend handling this in the `PropertyChange` notification in `MyClass`. To prevent changes, I would either include a property in `MyClass` which determines if the CheckBox can be changed or not, or disable the CheckBox in a trigger like above.

```
void MyClass_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "SelectedComboBoxItem")
    {
        if (SelectedComboBoxItem == "Enter")
        {
            IsAlwaysOn = false;
            CanChangeCheckBox = false;
        }
        else
        {
            CanChangeCheckBox = true;
        }
    }
}
```